# ftp command shows different file modification time

Tags: linux, ftp

When we use the `ftp` command or ftp client to connect to a Linux server, the files' modification time shown is different from the time shown in a `telnet` session.

For example, I have some `*.dat` files in `/home/abc/` and the last modification time shown in the `ftp` command or client is 19:30. But when I do an `ls -l` in my `telnet` session, it shows 03:30. The last modification time shown in the telnet session is correct.

Is there a setting that has gone wrong?

Comment: ftp? telnet?? 80's called, they want their protocols back. Are you talking about some embedded system or should you learn about sftp and ssh...? :-)

Comment: unfortunately we are still stuck in the 80's :P

Comment: Are you GMT+8, or is the time offset seemingly meaningless?

Comment: yes, my time zone here is GMT +8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 2 years, today I found out that the cause of the problem is because the FTP timestamps are set to GMT instead of following the correctly set timezone as highlighted in this [URL](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/712/How+do+I+fix+my+FTP+timestamps?#dv)

But in the URL, the change was done to the `/etc/proftpd.conf`. This Linux server is using vsftpd. So there is a slight change to the solution.

Edit the `vsftpd` configuration file and append this to it `use_localtime=YES`. Then restart `vsftpd`

Here is a more detailed step I did:

1. Logged in as a non-root user
2. `su` to `root`
3. Find which `ftpd` it is runnning. For this server it is using `vsftpd`

   `$ ps -ef | grep ftpd`
4. Make a copy of the configuration file.
5. Use an editor to edit the `vsftpd` configuration file.

   `$ vim /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`
6. Add the option `use_localtime` and set the value to `YES`. The default value is `NO`

   `use_localtime=YES`
7. Restart the ftpd service

   `$ /sbin/service vsftpd restart`

   `$ /sbin/service vsftpd status`
8. Retry login using ftp and check the file timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not positive about this, but perhaps is the timezone on your client set differently than on the server? That could cause your ftp client to display the time with an incorrect offset.

Comment: we tried connecting via ftp to that server on two different machines, which has the same timezone set as the server, and still the time is show differently that the one in the telnet session.

Answer (score 0):

I'd a similar problem with my FTP long ago, But both servers where on the same GMT zone... 
The problem was that the Software itself has a "GMT" configuration properties. ¿Have u checked all the possible configuration of the service and the server?

check NTP to, maybe he's updating after u manually put the right time.

Comment: then I have to check the time setting on the machine which connects to the server. We actually run a bat file which automatically connects to the server via ftp and mgets some files

Comment: ¿What client are u using? Standard windows? Standard Linux? I recomend WinScp, has scripting in "batch" file, in console, can delete afeter transfer... He has the option or preserving TimeStamp... maybe that works for u. http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_timestamp

Comment: in our bat file, it actually calls WinScp to connect to the server to get files and then move them to another directory.. i'll have to lookup the preserving TimeStamp in WinScp.. thanks

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment.. this has nothing to do with WinScp.. just verified with my colleagues.. my bad..